# Fail to load Spyder saved session?

Tags: session, spyder

I use Spyder in Ubuntu, I thought I could save the IPython interactive session using the "File -> Save session and quit" option. So for example, I define some variables in the Ipython interactive console, like

```
>>> x = 1
```

, then I click and save the session as file "1.session.tar". I close and open Spyder again and choose "File -> Load session", and I pick the session file, but when I open IPython console, there is no such a variable as I defined `x = 1`, why is that ? Spyder cannot save IPython interactive session?

Answer (score 3):

(*Spyder dev here*) The *Save session* option only saves your list of open files for the moment.

If you want to save your IPython session you can use the *Save data* or *Save data as* buttons from the Variable Explorer and save it as a `.mat` file (yes, the same format used by Matlab). Then, when you restart Spyder again, you need to load your data using the *Import data* button from the Variable Explorer again.

You need to be aware that:

1. Not all data is saved, only Python objects that can be serialized.
2. We are thinking to improve the situation in the future by saving your sessions automatically and by using `dill`, a library that can serialize everything.

Comment: Thanks, btw if I use `pickle`, then all the objects could be dumped?

Comment: That's the problem in the first place: we use `pickle` to serialize and dump objects to a `mat` file but `pickle` can't serialize everything.

Comment: Hi @Carlos Cordoba ! I was wondering if this is working in recent versions?

Comment: @Jaqo, sorry, unfortunately we haven't had time to improve the situation since this question.

Comment: I guess it would be OK if I ask again whether this feature is available now? :)

Comment: It is available with the limitations I mentioned above. We plan to fix this in Spyder 4, to be released in 2018.